# Interface section of m file?

Tags: objective-c

I have heard on an online course on Objective C that the the properties that appear in the interface section of an m files belong "to the storyboard file not to the controller" -and hence why they are "weak"- can someone explain this to me or point me towards a tutorial? How can it belong to the storyboard file if it's in the controller file?

Comment: no it is not correct!!! .h/.m files are related to both controller and storyboard. IF the properties are declared as outlets, they are related to storybaord, else related to controller!!!! Again you have options to declare the properties as strong or weak!!

Answer (score 0):

> belong "to the storyboard file not to the controller

This is inaccurate, they 'belong' to the controller.

These don't have to just be `IBOutlet` references, but that is a common usage. `IBOutlet`s are usually weak because they are subviews of the controllers view. The view retains its subviews so the controller doesn't have to. `IBOutlet`s can be strong, they just don't need to be. In practice it doesn't usually make a difference - just be consistent throughout the entire project and write comments if you deviate from your own standard for any reason...

Other properties (that aren't `IBOutlet`) have no link to the storyboard and the controller will usually maintain a strong reference (normal rules apply).